# Connection matrix in orientable 2-bundle is skew-symmetric

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

In the notes I am following to learn about connections, there is the following lemma:

[image]
whose proof is natural and I understand. Later in the text the author writes the following (referring to a metric connection):

[image]

I suppose this comes from the lemma above, but I do not see how. Is $\nabla$ somehow a metric connection just because we are dealing with an orientable bundle?

Comment: The written equality does certainly not hold for a general connection. You do not specify in your post the nature of your connection, but by the context, it seems that it is compatible with the metric.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval yes, I will add that.